# Angular Ui-router inline template not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angular-template

I'm New to Angular, and learning through the tutorials on [Thinkster](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails). I'm at the Angular Routing -> Adding a New State step.

I am trying to use ui-router to render an inline template, but the template is not appearing. Here is my `index.html` (abridged) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- My js files are loaded here -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app='flapperNews'>

    <div class ='row'>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
      <!-- My template written as plain html>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is how my routing is currently handled in `app.js` :

```
angular.module('flapperNews',['ui.router'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    return;

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

}]);
```

It is my understanding that ui-router should parse the url and render the appropriate template within the div ui-view tags. (Thinkster says the tag should be 'ui-view' but the [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/legacy) seemed to indicate otherwise; I have tried both ).

My page renders blank, and there are no errors logged to the console. For what its worth, I am doing the tutorial with just local files, and since I've added the routing code my url has a # appended to it i.e `file://blah/blah/FlapperNews/index.html#` and I'm unsure why.

Comment: try with ng-include

Comment: why there is a `return;` right after the `function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){`? u didn't do any configuration in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tries the following code and seem to work. It is based on the link you provided.

What I fixed from your code:

1. id="home.html" to id="/home.html"
2. comment is not closed: `<!-- My template written as plain html>`
3. delete `return;` from config function
4. removed controller since there wasn't any code for it

---

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body ng-app='flapperNews'>

      <div class ='row'>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
        test content
      </script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
        .config([
          '$stateProvider',
          '$urlRouterProvider',
          function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
              url: '/home',
              templateUrl: '/home.html'
              // controller: 'MainCtrl'
            });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
          }])
        </script>

      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks - not sure how that return got in there, but I was totally missing the "/" in the id! Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `return` in your configuration function.

```
angular.module('flapperNews',['ui.router'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

}]);
```